# Please convert the following piece of code from python2 to python3 for me

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been trying to use urllib3 and achieve the purpose of the following code using urllib3's methods bit now I'm stuck. Please tell me how this code would translate into the urllib3 module.

```
import urllib2,json   
READ_API_KEY='KT1CQ2Q0V9G7ABRU'
CHANNEL_ID=215609
def main():
    conn = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/feeds/last.json?api_key=%s"% (CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY))
    response = conn.read()
    data=json.loads(response)
    print(data['field1'],data['created_at'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: urllib3 and Python 3 are completely different things. Neither tool forces you to use the other.

Answer (score 0):

you could try urllib.request.urlopen()

> The legacy urllib.urlopen function from Python 2.6 and earlier has been discontinued; urllib.request.urlopen() corresponds to the old urllib2.urlopen.

docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen